# How do I display error message for each h:inputText inside h:dataTable?

Tags: validation, jsf, datatable

I need to display error messages after validation has failed for each h:inputText inside h:dataTable. Here is the code:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myBean.dataList}" var="dataItem">

<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Name" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:inputText id="name" value="#{dataItem.name}" />
</h:column>

<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Value" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:inputText id="value" value="#{dataItem.value}" />
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

When I tried to put:

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{dataItem.name}" />
<h:message for="name"/>
```

It returns:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.augmentIdReference(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:196)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
<h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">
          <h:outputText value="Name" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:inputText id="name" value="#{dataItem.name}" required="true" requiredMessage="Mandatory"/>              

     <h:message for="name" id="msg"/>

</h:column>
```

You haven't bound your `<h:message></h:message>` to your `<h:inputText></h:inputText>`. I have simply made the `<h:inputText></h:inputText>` to be a mandatory field. You may need to use some *validators* as and when required to suit your requirements.

Comment: As in my first post, I tried that before, but it threw the error

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a Mojarra 1.2 version older than 1.2_14. This is known as [issue 941](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-941) which is been fixed in 1.2_14. The currently latest Mojarra 1.2 is 1.2_15. You can [download](http://java.net/downloads/javaserverfaces/release/1.2_15/mojarra-1.2_15-b01-FCS-binary.zip) it [here](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html). Replace both the `jsf-api.jar` and `jsf-impl.jar` and you should be all set. Your code is fine, by the way.

Comment: Thank you very muhc. Let me try that.